# I want to have no duplicate values in Course, and want to keep the course with the LEAST discount, and delete the rest of the duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Input**

| Courses | Fee | Duration | Discount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Spark | 20000 | 30days | 1000 |
| PySpark | 25000 | 40days | 2300 |
| pandas | 10000 | 10days | 1 |
| Python | 22000 | 35days | 1200 |
| pandas | 30000 | 50days | 2000 |
| pandas | 400000 | 70days | 2 |

**Desired Output**

| Courses | Fee | Duration | Discount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Spark | 20000 | 30days | 1000 |
| PySpark | 25000 | 40days | 2300 |
| pandas | 10000 | 10days | 1 |
| Python | 22000 | 35days | 1200 |

**2 rows with Courses = pandas have been deleted, keeping the one with the least discount**

Comment: 2 with same least discount?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest taking a look at [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) for drop_duplicates. As `subset` you want `df["Courses"]` and as `keep` you can choose `"first"` or `"last"`. To make sure the first is always lowest you can first sort the dataframe by how much discount they have: `df.sort_values(by="Discount", inplace=True)`